# How to check in angularjs if ng-model has a value of string or a number?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have my *java script* in angular checking if the value of text field is undefined or empty, it is fine and working,

```js
$scope.checkNumber = function(user_answer){
 if(user_answer == undefined){
   return false;     
 }
}
```

But my next step is how I can make a function to identify if the value has a string or a number and return a boolean. I don't know the right syntax for angular *java script*, can anyone help me to solve my problem?

Comment: have you tried typeof , its inbuilt into JS

Comment: if you want to have a number only textfield, use <input type='number'>

Comment: @lcycool <input type='number'> doesn't prevent you from inputting strings

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this the angular way, using the angular helper functions:

```
$scope.checkNumber = function(user_answer){
    if(angular.isUndefined(user_answer)){
      return false;                 
    }
    if(angular.isString(user_answer)) {
       //return boolean
    }
    if(angular.isNumber(user_answer)) {
       //return boolean
    }
}
```

Comment: @JustAce I'm not sure I understand what you mean

Comment: It's working now, human error only, thank you for this. I just need to reconstruct my codes to make some a conditions. Thank you again =)

Answer (score 3):

Try like this

```
function check(text){     
 return typeof text ==="number";
}
```

Comment: Do I need to convert my fetched data to a string or number before do this function?

Comment: Thank you @Anik Islam Abhi, I've found another solution. But your approach of codes helped me too. Thank you again. =)